# Imagens getImageUrl()

Tags: android

Estou a carregar imagens assim:

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) firstElementView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
String src = item.getImageUrl(); 
img.setTag(src);
imageLoader.displayImage(src, img, Utils.getImageLoaderOptions());
```

Mas agora preciso de ir buscar imagens por url através de uma API, isto é, o url não se encontra disponível directamente, é preciso fazer umas chamada primeiro por `httpurlconnect()`.

Soluções? Fazer *download* da imagem via `httpurlconnect` e depois mostrar a imagem? Como fazer dessa maneira? Que outro tipo de soluções há?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido com:

Usei:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
```

para conseguir ter a imagem em Bitmap e depois usei:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode baixar as imagens em background para que o usuário não tenha que ficar esperando a imagem ser baixada e depois apenas carrega-las usando a url ou o sistema de cache.

Segue um artigo falando sobre esse assunto.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url

http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-load-image-from-internet.html

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/

Espero ter ajudado!

Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, foi mais fácil que parecia. Usei:
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
para conseguir ir o Bitmap e depois usei: imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `Picasso`.

`Picasso` é uma biblioteca muito popular e utilizada no desenvolvimento Android que resolve todo o problema de carregamento e processamento de imagens para você e também simplifica a exibição de imagens de terceiros (como por exemplo, URL's). O `Picasso` faz desde a requisição (`HTTP`) até o cache desta imagem para a utilização futura.

1) Adicione o `Picasso` no seu `build.gradle` e sincronize seu projeto:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

2) Caso não tenha, adicione a permissão de internet em seu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

3) Crie uma `ImageView` qualquer para exibir a sua imagem:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/suaImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

4) Agora, em sua `Activity` (ou `Fragment` ou qualquer outro lugar que queira exibir uma imagem) basta referenciar sua `ImageView` e dizer para o `Picasso` carregar a sua URL:

```
ImageView suaImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.suaImageView);

Picasso.with(this)
        .load("http://www.dominio.com.br/imagem.jpg")
        .into(suaImageView);
```

Você também tem a possibilidade de manipular a sua imagem, como por exemplo:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  //Definindo uma resolução para sua imagem
  .resize(50, 50)
  //Definindo um Scale Type para a sua imagem
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

**Links**:

Página oficial do `Picasso`: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Página do `GitHub` do `Picasso`: https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, foi mais fácil que parecia. Usei:
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
para conseguir ir o Bitmap e depois usei: imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: @MicaelCosta tome cuidado com essa abordagem! Isso pode "congelar" a tela do usuário, já que, carregar imagens, é considerado uma tarefa pesada para ser executada na thread principal (UI thread). Se você for realmente implementar desta maneira, recomendo que leia este artigo http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html (Lembrando que o Picasso já resolve todo esse problema para você)